# How can I group photos by dates when browsing a folder via Adobe Bridge?

Tags: date, photos, adobe-bridge

When browsing a folder via Adobe Bridge, one can sort photos by creation or modification dates. How can I visually group photos by dates? Eg, group of photos taken yesterday, group of photos taken two day ago, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Adobe Bridge does not have the option to visually group photos by dates. One would need to use a different program to have this feature.